# Windows firewall blocking inbound port 9000 (xdebug), even though inbound rule created

Tags: lamp, windows-firewall, eclipse, xdebug

I have been trying to allow computer A (LAMP with xdebug configured) connect to computer B (Eclipse IDE with xdebug) via port 9000. Both are on running on my local network. I created an inbound rule to allow connections to port 9000, but connections are still blocked. The blocked connections to port 9000 appear to be dropped in my windows firewall log. However, if I turn off my windows firewall, connections to port 9000 are allowed. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Running netstat -ab in windows cmd revealved that the javaw.exe process created the 9000 listening port. Inbound connections to the javaw.exe process (Java(TM) Platform SE binary) were being blocked in windows firewall. Disabling this rule fixed the problem and inbound connection to port 9000 are now allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the inbound rule you created to see what profile it is using, under the Advanced tab.  If the rule is for the private profile, and the NIC has decided it's in the public profile, you'd get the symptoms you are describing.

Comment: the profile it uses is: domain, private and public. The NIC is using the private profile. Also this inbound rule is applied to all interfaces